# Add Imap Folder Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit

Im trying to add a top level folder using Mailkit so when I add the following labels I am able to group them under this folder.

The labels are:

- mailkit/archive
- mailkit/flagged

I want to create a folder called mailkit so gmail groups them but I cannot seem to find a way to do this currently. Is this possible, does anyone have an example?

Comment: So? That's not a valid question for here. Perhaps you should read the rules before you ask anything else.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask does anyone have an example of how to do this.. I updated the question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an example of what you need to do:

```
var toplevel = client.GetFolder (client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
var mailkit = toplevel.Create ("mailkit", false);
var archive = mailkit.Create ("archive", true);
var flagged = mailkit.Create ("flagged", true);
```

Hope that helps.